# How to enable two locales at once with #pragma in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, setlocale

As far as I know you can set your language with:

```
#pragma setlocale("language")
```

However you can only set it to one language. Anyone knows how to enable two languages in the same form in C++? Lithuanian and Russian in this case.

Comment: This is not standard C++ but rather specific to some implementation. You should add what implementation (compiler/platform)

Comment: What is a special symbol language? Is it the one you use to say @#$!?

Comment: WTF is a "special symbol language"?

Comment: [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e22ty2t(v=vs.100).aspx)  it's #pragma too.

Comment: It's MSVC `#pragma` extension.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what you want to see?  Adhering to two locales at the same time would be contradictory.  Do you want different elements of the form to adhere to different locales?

Comment: When displaying my content I have a mix of lithuanian (ąčęėįųū) and russian symbols. Problem is I can't get them both to be displayed at the same time.

If I set no locale I can use the lithuanian characters but get "?"'s intead of russian ones. If I set the locale to russian my lithuanian characters get replaced with russian ones.

Comment: @Matt try using UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what you specifically want is to support the character set of both languages.

You can support all supported Unicode characters by specifying the character encoding `UTF-8` in the locale.

```
#pragma setlocale("any_language.UTF-8")
```

Microsoft covers some details of using a multibyte character set [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ey142t48%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Windows doesn't really support UTF-8. The standard way to get Unicode is not to use locales at all. You just use `wchar_t` with UTF-16 characters.

Comment: @CodyGray you're saying that in Windows, wchar_t would support UTF-16 naturally?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Hard to find good documentation for this, maybe [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407.aspx)?

Comment: @CodyGray that's interesting. You have my upvote if you can give a more informed answer.